# How to integrate libvirt with libxl of Xen 4.4?

Tags: virtualization, xen

I'm running Xen 4.4 with Ubuntu 14.04 without any problems, like this:

```
root@hyper-xen-1:~# xl li
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  5431     8     r-----   32652.8
svr01                                       19  4096     4     -b----   28842.6
app-1                                       29  2048     4     -b----    4906.0
svr02                                       31  2048     4     -b----    4186.5
svr03                                       32  2048     4     -b----    5216.1
```

But, libvirt is unable to see those running virtual machines, look:

```
root@hyper-xen-1:~# virsh -c xen:///system list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
```

So, how can I fully integrate libvirt, with Xen when using libxl ? Also, the virt-manager isn't working either...

Thanks in advance!

Best,
Thiago

Answer (score 1):

two quick google searches brought up a host of info. I am not sure if you have looked through these sources so I thought I would point you to them.

- Jim Fehlig of Suse has a long post explaining "libvirt support for Xen’s new libxenlight toolstack" (http://jfehlig.wordpress.com/2014/01/05/libvirt-support-for-xens-new-libxenlight-toolstack/)
- Anil Madhavapeddy has a very long and detailed note about libvirt here (http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.emulators.xen.devel/201602)

Why don't I just copy the contents here? Because I think you will be able to get more from those notes than I could care to explain. :)

Please read those and let us know if those notes resolve your problem.

Thanks

Comment: Hello thatmaheshrs, I already read those messages, didn't helped me... Including this one: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libvirt/+bug/1180281 ...  I'm looking for a more direct / simple configuration instructions, since it seems that I'm almost there (virsh/libvirt connects at xen:///system but, doesn't list), but thanks anyway!

Comment: @ThiagoCMC it is my understanding that the first link I gave you almost clearly says that the things you wanna do CANNOT be done currently. Jim Felig is one of the prominent developers for libvirt and associated drivers. That was the only reason I gave you that link.

Comment: I must confess that I did not read it entirely, and I was assuming that it was working, because the official libvirt webpage http://libvirt.org/drvxen.html says it works through libxl... I'll read it again... Thank you for your time!

Comment: so does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems as you with existing xen guests, when I initially installed libvirt in order to manage my xen guests with virt-manager; however, slightly different: I could see xen `xl` created guests in `virsh list`, but using the following command:

```
user@server:~$ virsh -c xen:/// list --all
 Id    Name                           State
----------------------------------------------------
 1     core                           running
```

And `xl list` showed the dom0 and guest:

```
root@server:~# xl list
Name                                        ID   Mem VCPUs      State   Time(s)
Domain-0                                     0  1020     4     r-----      35.0
core                                         1  1023     1     -b----      25.6
```

The main difference is, I could see newly created guests in the virt-manager console, but not the existing xen create guests

I ended up rebuilding the xen guests via virt-manager, whereas I had originally created them using `xl create`

In retrospect, I now realise it may possible/necessary to convert the config for the `xl` created guests to libvirt XML - http://libvirt.org/drvxen.html

I'd not considered this a possibility until having read further in the libvirt docs.